# Is there better way to process messages received in a queue from the on_message callback?

Tags: python, multithreading, queue, paho, concurrent.futures

I currently have my paho-MQTT client script with a message queue and a on_message callback function.

```
    def on_message(self, client, _, message):
        message = message.payload.decode()
        self.messageQueue.put_nowait(message)
```

i need to do some processing on these received messages (I get around 12 messages in the queue every 3 seconds)

how can i process these messages safely ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a robust distributed queue mechanism, you can implement using python celery where your **on_message** would act as a producer which placed task on broker. And multiple workers/consumers would be running on different machines and consuming tasks from broker.

Link: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/introduction.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a way to implement this without external libraries and minimize the overhead ?